# Software & Updates won't launch at all

Tags: 20.04, python

If I click on Software & Updates, it doesn't do anything at all.

When I try to run it from the command line (both with and without root), it shows this error:

```py
$ sudo software-properties-gtk 
ERROR:dbus.proxies:Introspect error on :1.162:/: dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-properties-gtk", line 100, in <module>
    app = SoftwarePropertiesGtk(datadir=options.data_dir, options=options, file=file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py", line 211, in __init__
    self.backend.Reload();
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 72, in __call__
    return self._proxy_method(*args, **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 141, in __call__
    return self._connection.call_blocking(self._named_service,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 652, in call_blocking
    reply_message = self.send_message_with_reply_and_block(
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name :1.162 was not provided by any .service files
```

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.1 on an ASUS X550za. Any ideas?

The output of `apt list software-properties-gtk -a`, as per the suggestion:

```
Listing... Done
software-properties-gtk/focal-updates,focal-updates,now 0.98.9.3 all [installed,automatic]
software-properties-gtk/focal-security,focal-security 0.98.9.2 all
software-properties-gtk/focal,focal 0.98.9 all
```

<strike>I just tried to run nutty on my computer, but I got a similar error message:</strike>

```
$ nutty
[_LOG_LEVEL_INFO 18:41:28.656400] Application.vala:153: Nutty version: 0.9
[_LOG_LEVEL_INFO 18:41:28.656474] Application.vala:155: Kernel version: 5.4.0-54-generic
Failed to register: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Connection ":1.114" is not allowed to own the service "org.nutty" due to AppArmor policy
```

Could this be related? It isn't.

Comment: Maybe stupid question. Somewhere configured proxy settings?

Comment: A different error means a completely different problem. A DBus error generally indicates an internal problem (like a missing file or bug). Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1294999/edit) to show us the complete output of `apt list software-properties-gtk -a`

Comment: @nobody I don't have any proxy settings configured.

Comment: @user535733 I edited it.

Comment: Did you do something to python on your system?

Comment: Try re-installing software-properties-gtk: `sudo apt install --reinstall software-properties-gtk`

Comment: @user535733 Reinstalling didn't change the error :|

Comment: @OrganicMarble Not in any way that I can think of. I've installed a few things with pip, but that shouldn't affect anything.

Comment: There are several possible causes for the DBus error, but most of them cause spectacular failures all over the system: A problem with DBus itself (most of your desktop simply wouldn't work), a missing component of apt (other package actions would fail), a wrong version of Python3 (lots of other desktop and apt failures), a wrong DBus Session bus (I don't know how that could even happen), and a few other unlikely candidates. Any of those seem familiar?

Comment: Remove the pip stuff if possible. I break my python with only one of them.

Comment: @user535733 I don't remember messing with any of that, but I can try to reinstall python3 / python2

Comment: @nobody Will do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-properties/+bug/1900098) for some updates coming from Ubuntu. The solution is simple:

```bash
sudo apt reinstall python3-six python3-certifi
```