# Software & Updates not launching, dbus.exceptions.DBusException

Tags: 20.04, dbus

Somehow I've managed to break my Software & Updates app. Running via the GUI, the app simply doesn't launch. When I run the command `software-properties-gtk` I get this output:

```
ERROR:dbus.proxies:Introspect error on :1.226:/: dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-properties-gtk", line 100, in <module>
    app = SoftwarePropertiesGtk(datadir=options.data_dir, options=options, file=file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py", line 222, in __init__
    self.backend.Reload();
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 72, in __call__
    return self._proxy_method(*args, **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 141, in __call__
    return self._connection.call_blocking(self._named_service,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 652, in call_blocking
    reply_message = self.send_message_with_reply_and_block(
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name :1.226 was not provided by any .service files
```

I've tried reinstalling `software-properties-gtk` and even `ubuntu-desktop` to no avail, the same issue occurs.

I also tried the solutions offered here but nothing helps:

- https://askubuntu.com/a/1388327/1548054
- https://askubuntu.com/a/1308738/1548054

Answer (score 0):

I find that this is usually an issue with Python dependencies used in these files either not installed or somehow broken.

Please try the following: `sudo apt install --reinstall python3-apt python3-dbus python3-gi`

I got these packages by checking the imported libraries in the python files referenced in the exception:

```
grep "import" /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py
grep "import" /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py
grep "import" /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately that didn't fix the issue either.

Answer (score 0):

One working solution I was found:
Remove all /usr/lib/python3 and /usr/lib/python3.8
Next, copy it from a working Ubuntu installation.

If you don't have from where to copy the files, remove all above will broke your system forever (specially apt and you will not be able to install anything). Please don't do it if you don't have another working Ubuntu system to copy files from.

You can install an Ubuntu on a virtual machine, of course it must be the same version that you are using.

That showed me there are some broken files under python libraries. Further investigation is needed.
Instead of deleting you can rename and next compare what differences are and maybe you can figure out what is wrong.